# Ubunutu full screen atrifacts

Tags: browser, fullscreen

I've got a problem with full screen in browser. When I turn on full screen for browser, artifacts begin to appear, sometimes it turns black. The video card is fine because on Windows I checked this functionality worked.

Comment: We're limited to details you provide, and currently we don't know what Ubuntu product you're asking about, what release of that product, nor have any details about your hardware (*and if a LTS release, what kernel stack you're using as that can influence the kernel, kernel modules (aka drivers) being used & can make a difference on new/older hardware*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled the drivers and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In browser, you can switch "Hardware acceleration" option.